# Cancel form.submit()

Tags: asp.net, javascript

In javascript function I am submitin a form:
  `form.submit();`,

with huge amount of data.

Is it possible to cancel this operation beside clicking on browser's stop button?

**UPDATE:**

Maybe i didn't made my self clear i am submiting large files.
form with uploadcontrol that runs in iframe.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like what Gmail does: Undo Sending Mails (lab feature).

It justs delays the mail sending by a 5 seconds. If in that time the server receives a `undo` AJAX call, the mail is not send.

This could potentially increase you serverside complexity, but not that much.

In the case that the information is not sent you could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336197/cancel-form-submit/1336227#1336227):

```
//IE
document.execCommand('Stop');
//Firefox
window.stop();
```

So the whole thing would look something like this (pseudocode):

```
stop_submit(current_id){
    try{
        document.execCommand('Stop');
    }catch(e){}
    try{
        window.stop();
    }catch(e){}

    AJAXCall("/myfolder/cancel_submit/", "id="+current_id, "post");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem with the client-server architecture. Once the HTTP request has been made, there is no stopping it. You will need a way to restore state after all requests to guarantee that everything is back to the way it was.

Now, you could do this with AJAX and use the `abort` function. Or, you could try `window.stop()` or `document.execCommand("Stop")`, depending on your browser. But those do not solve the problem of the request having already been sent.